# Way of collapsing set of rules into few universal rules - mathematical Occam's razor

Tags: combinatorics, philosophy

I was thinking about learning rules of a system by just looking at it. Let's say you know nothing about chess and you watch inifinite number of games - you watched all possible transitions of states. If you are dumb(or a neural network) you can write really big set of rules, where each state can evolve into all possible next states and call it rules. It's pretty easy to guess that you would end up with billions of billions of rules - this goes very much against Occam's razor.

Let's simplify the problem then. Let's say we have $x$ by $x$ chessboard and just one tower - we watch infinite moves of this tower. Now we can derive rules of this system, let's say again we are dumb and come up with separate rules that say that from any $x*x$ possible positions we can move to any other $2(x-1)$ positions, but these are all SEPARATE rules. How could we "collapse" this enormous set of rules into something more comprehensible and UNIVERSAL?

I would like to say in advance: I am really sorry for not using a lot of mathematical notation, this problem was a bit more philosophical in my mind and I am not advanced enough in this field of mathematics to write something that makes sense.

Comment: Find similarities. A human will immediately notice that all possible end-positions of the tower lie on the cross determined by the $x$ and $y$coordinate. For a machine this will be harder though as it has to learn the concept of a line / cross first. (Technically this holds for humans as well, but nevermind)

Comment: Interesting that you example Occam's razor with Chess, since (oversimplifying) there are 3 chess camps; superGrandMasters at one end of the spectrum that use Occam's razor re pattern recognition (i.e. pawn islands), *middle-of-the-road* traditional chess software organized rule evaluation approaches (e.g. Stockfish) and (at the other extreme) recent AI (e.g. Alpha Zero) that doesn't even know what a bishop is, let alone what its worth.  The AI move selection is based on an ultra large neural network of what it has *learned*.  Going from human to machine, Occam's Razor becomes less critical.

Comment: I guess you don't need infinite number of games since it is finite even though it can be quite large. Then your question can be reduced to 'given all of its possible moves find the rules that the most concise' which is reduced to 'find the most concise program that can detact if given inputs are valid or not.' which is I don't think its possible and only approximations may be possible in a limited way like other people are saying. this seems to be related to kolmogorov complexity.

Comment: Not very clear... Why do you think that an "intelligent" agent (human or machine) exposed to a finite and limited number of chess plays cannot find the correct rule (only one and very simple) governing the tower possible moves?

Answer (score 1):

A 'mathematical Occam's razor' is the [minimum description length principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_description_length).

Roughly speaking it states that the best model for a set of observations is the number of bits needed to represent that model, plus the number of bits needed to represent the corrections to the model for observations it gets wrong. The model that minimizes this sum is the best model for a set of observations.

Note that this (just like Occam's razor) does not tell you how to *find* this model. But it can, given two models, tell you which of the two is better.

As for finding these models, well that's an entire field: machine learning. Tons upon tons of methods exist (linear models, decision trees, (convolutional) neural networks, (non-linear) SVMs, rule-based models, etc).